# Query is executing twice

Tags: php, mysql, sql, function

On my website I am trying to execute two queries in one but both are executing twice.

When I create a member I got two the same members in the database for the first query.

The second query isn't doing `+1` but twice `+1` so it makes `+2`.

```
if (isset($_POST["Accept"])) {
    try {
        $group_id = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["group_id"]);
        $groupinfo = $group->GetGroupInfoByGroupId($group_id);
        $groupname = $groupinfo['group_name'];

        $requestnumber = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['acceptID']);

        $groupinvitation->Invitation_group_name = mysql_real_escape_string($groupname);
        $groupinvitation->AddAsGroupMember($number, $group_id);
        $r->UpdateParticipatedGroups($StatisticsRows, $participatedGroups);
        $groupinvitation-> AcceptGroupRequest($requestnumber);

        $feedback = "Awesome, You just added a friend!";

    } catch(Exception $e) {
        $feedback = $e -> getMessage();
    }
```

functions:

```
public function AddAsGroupMember($number, $group_id)
{
    $db = new Db();
    $insert = "
        INSERT INTO tblgroup_member(  
            group_id,
            user_id,
            group_name

      ) VALUES (

            '" . $db->conn->real_escape_string($group_id) . "',
            '" . $db->conn->real_escape_string($number) . "',
            '" . $db->conn->real_escape_string($this->Invitation_group_name) . "'   
      )";

    $db->conn->query($insert);
    // update number of members
    $select = "UPDATE tblgroups SET group_members =  group_members + 1 WHERE " .  $group_id . " = group_id";    
    $db->conn->query($select);
}
```

Comment: Is all the code being called twice, not just the SQL? Is it possible that the code is just being called twice? Say, a browser refresh somehow?

Comment: just as a side comment - shouldnt you update the count AFTER the insert statement? Because you will have a +1 even if the insert fails...

Comment: Only this function... 1 makes always 2...

Comment: One another thing to check, if there is any trigger on the insert event into tblgroup_member

Comment: Are you sure no other functions aren't also calling/executing this function?

Comment: I don't use this function somewhere else...

Comment: Di  you tried a simple debug adding something like echo 'here I am'; for example in AddAsGroupMember function? How many time do you get the output? If you comment the function call what's happen?

Comment: Sounds like the function is being called twice...

Comment: Data is duplicating Filo

Comment: Do you get "here I am" twice? It means that the function is called twice (like others users said). Did you tried to comment this line?         $groupinvitation->AddAsGroupMember($number, $group_id);  do you still get "her I am"?

Comment: Damn lord, when I remove the function it's working correctly, but I can't find the other function call... weird

Comment: Just a side note - You should be using prepared statements with PDO or  MySQLi because mysql_* functions are becoming deprectaed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's make a simple debug

replace you code with this and you should be able to understand more about the function call.

```
if (isset($_POST["Accept"])) {
    try {
    echo 'main 0\n'; 
    $group_id = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["group_id"]);
    echo 'main 1\n';
    $groupinfo = $group->GetGroupInfoByGroupId($group_id);
    echo 'main 2\n';
    $groupname = $groupinfo['group_name'];

    $requestnumber = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['acceptID']);

    $groupinvitation->Invitation_group_name = mysql_real_escape_string($groupname);
    echo 'main 3\n';
    $groupinvitation->AddAsGroupMember($number, $group_id);
    echo 'main 4\n';
    $r->UpdateParticipatedGroups($StatisticsRows, $participatedGroups);
    echo 'main 5\n';
    $groupinvitation-> AcceptGroupRequest($requestnumber);
    echo 'main 6\n';

    $feedback = "Awesome, You just added a friend!";


} catch(Exception $e) {
    $feedback = $e -> getMessage();

}
```

and the function

```
public function AddAsGroupMember($number, $group_id)
    {
            echo 'func 1\n';
            $db = new Db();
            $insert = "INSERT INTO tblgroup_member(


                            group_id,
                            user_id,
                            group_name


                      ) VALUES (

                            '" . $db->conn->real_escape_string($group_id) . "',
                            '" . $db->conn->real_escape_string($number) . "',
                            '" . $db->conn->real_escape_string($this->Invitation_group_name) . "'   



                      )";

        $db->conn->query($insert);
            echo 'func 2\n';
// update number of members
        $select = "UPDATE tblgroups SET group_members =  group_members + 1 WHERE " .  $group_id . " = group_id";    
    $db->conn->query($select);
    echo 'func 3\n';
    }
```

---

Another (better) way to make a simple debug is calling [debug_print_backtrace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.debug-print-backtrace.php) inside AddAsGroupMember